# Writing a yield generator function based on a given task

Tags: python, yield

This is part of a code, that should run a record search in chunks of 1000 records:

```
  for subrange, batch in batched(records, size=1000):
      print("Processing records %d-%d" %
        (subrange[0], subrange[-1]))
      process(batch)
```

I need to write a `yield` generator function for it, so far, I've tried like this:

```
def batched(records, chunk_size=1000):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read records piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = records.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
```

The problem statement is as follows:

```
For optimal performance, records should be processed in batches.
Create a generator function "batched" that will yield batches of 1000
records at a time
```

I'm not quite sure on how to test the function either, so, any ideas?

PS = The `batched` generator function is supposed to precede the given for `subrange` loop.

Comment: Your `batched()` doesn't fulfill the requirements: it accepts `chunk_size` instead of `size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your given loop code

```
for subrange, batch in batched(records, size=1000):
    print("Processing records %d-%d" %
      (subrange[0], subrange[-1]))
    process(batch)
```

has implicit requirements for `batched()`:

1. It should return an iterable. This is indeed fulfilled by a generator function.
2. The items yielded should be tuples `subrange, batch`. The subrange seems to be a list of indexes of all elements, a list or tuple of just the start and end indexes, or maybe a `range()` object. I'll assume the latter.

Alas, we don't know anything about the `records` object which is given. If it has a `read()` function, your approach can just be adjusted:

```
def batched(records, size=1000):
    """Generator function to read records piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    index = 0
    while True:
        data = records.read(size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield range(index, index + len(data)), data
        index += len(data)
```

But if `records` is just a list which should be broken down, you can just do

```
def batched(records, size=1000):
    """Generator function to read records piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    index = 0
    while True:
        data = records[index:index + size]
        if not data:
            break
        yield range(index, index + len(data)), data
        index += len(data)
```

Comment: Very nicely explained, Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

```
def batched(records, chunk_size=1000):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read records piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    pos = 0
    while True:
        data = records.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield ([pos, pos + len(data)], data )
        pos += len(data)
```